# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel for Office 2007

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-office, office-interop

I want to try the Windows form application that converts a office file (Excel, Word, Powerpoint) into a PDF file.
My client's PC will not install Visual Studio and Office version is 2007.
My application uses `Microsoft.Office.Iterop.Excel.dll` to covert to the PDF format.
This dll file cannot be found on my client's PC and an error has occurred as following.

```
System.AugumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook.ExportAsFixedFromat(.......)
```

How can I solve this problem?

My code is following

```
public bool ExportWorkbookToPdf(string workbookPath, string outputPath)
        {
            // If either required string is null or empty, stop and bail out
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(workbookPath) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(outputPath))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Create COM Objects
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApplication;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook;

            // Create new instance of Excel
            excelApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            // Make the process invisible to the user
            excelApplication.ScreenUpdating = false;

            // Make the process silent
            excelApplication.DisplayAlerts = false;

            // Open the workbook that you wish to export to PDF
            excelWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath);

            MessageBox.Show(workbookPath);
            // If the workbook failed to open, stop, clean up, and bail out
            if (excelWorkbook == null)
            {
                excelApplication.Quit();

                excelApplication = null;
                excelWorkbook = null;
                MessageBox.Show("in null");
                return false;
            }

            var exportSuccessful = true;
            try
            {
                // Call Excel's native export function (valid in Office 2007 and Office 2010, AFAIK)
                excelWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, outputPath);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                // Mark the export as failed for the return value...
                exportSuccessful = false;

                // Do something with any exceptions here, if you wish...
                // MessageBox.Show...        
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close the workbook, quit the Excel, and clean up regardless of the results...
                excelWorkbook.Close();
                excelApplication.Quit();

                excelApplication = null;
                excelWorkbook = null;
            }

            // You can use the following method to automatically open the PDF after export if you wish
            // Make sure that the file actually exists first...
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(outputPath))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(outputPath);
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(outputPath);
            }

            return exportSuccessful;
        }
```

Comment: Excel is installed on the machine right? Can you share the code where you get this error?

Comment: I installed the Office 2007 on the machine.Error was occured at "excelWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, outputPath);"

Comment: Does outputPath contain a path, or a filename with a path?

Comment: Filename with a path.[e.g,C:\\Test.pdf]

Comment: And sorry for posting the German link, but: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff198122(v=office.15).aspx says "If the PDF add-in is not installed, an error will occur". Maybe this is the case?

Comment: Why "c:\\test.pdf", not "c:\test.pdf"? Oh yeah, C#

Comment: Ok.Thanks alot.I will try it.Possibly PDF add-in has not been installed.

Comment: My client's PC is window 8.1.Thus PDF can read default Reader Application.How can I work around for this?

Comment: It is also possible to deactivate PDF exporting by a system policy. Check the registry keys `SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\<version>\common\fixedformat` and a value of `DisablePublishToFixedFormat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said in the comments, each client needs to install the [2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9943). It doesn't matter if you are on Windows 8.1 or have any PDF reader installed. You need that Add-in to write PDFs with Office 2007. (You don't need any Add-In with Office 2010 or 2013.)